# Insert length of #defined string literal at first entry of literal at compile time

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c-strings

I'm writing a C-Program with ESP-ZigbeeSDK where I need to set an default string, like `#define mystring`. But ZigBee requires that the first char of the literal indicates the length of the string `#define 0x08mystring` without `\0`.
Is there a way to do this at compile time?

Comment: I don't think there's any type of `strlen()` in the preprocessor.

Comment: Does this need to be a C program, or would you be open to using C++?

Comment: Sounds like "Pascal style" strings, so maybe calculate it by hand if you have to.

Comment: If your compiler supports the `-D` preprocessor option, you can try something like `cc -o program program.c -D$(printf "mystring" | wc -c | xargs printf "0x%02xmystring")="whatever"` from the command line. Which expands to `cc -o program program.c -D0x08mystring="whatever"`

Comment: @Brian61354270 I wouldn't mind using C++ but I've only ever used it for desktop developement. I don't know how difficult it would be to get it running with ESP-IDF

Comment: There is no need to do everything with the C preprocessor. Create your own syntax, like `Zigbee("string")`, write a little program to transform that to the Zigbee syntax, and run that program as part of your build procedure.

Comment: @DavidRanieri identifiers can't begin with a digit

Comment: @M.M yes, I know, I'm just quoting OP: `#define 0x08mystring`

Comment: @DavidRanieri I think they intended something like `#define mystring "\x08mystring"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"first char of the literal indicates the length of the string" --> *String literal* `"\010mystring"` may work for OP - I am unable to perform a ZigBee test. `\010` is an octal escape sequence with a value of 8.  Octal escape sequences are up to 3 digits.

`"\x8mystring"` and `"\x08mystring"` may work too but are problematic, in general, if the following character, after the `8` is a hexadecimal digit. Hexadecimal escape sequences have no length limit.

If wanting to use a hexadecimal escape sequence or short octal one, split it off like `"\x0C" "abcdmystring"` or `"\11" "2mystring"` and let string literal concatenation put together.  That way the hex/octal sequence is certainly limited. [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963195/insert-length-of-defined-string-literal-at-first-entry-of-literal-at-compile-ti/76964313?noredirect=1#comment135678202_76964313)

Comment: `"\x08""mystring"` works for all short strings even if they start with a digit.